# Symfony error with Varnish HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found returned for "http://localhost:8585/"

Tags: php, docker, symfony, varnish, api-platform.com

I tried to follow this documentation : https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.6/core/performance/
which is sadly a bit poor in order to configure varnish with api platform.

For the information I have PHP outside docker (directly installed on my computer) and Symfony is started like this :

`symfony server:start --allow-http --port 8000 -d --no-tls`

And I added Varnish inside a docker-composer.yml like this :

```
varnish:
    image: varnish:7.3.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - "./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - "8585:80"
```

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "host.docker.internal";
    .port = "8000";
}
```

When tried to to something in my backoffice (http://localhost:8000/admin)
I have the following error : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found returned for "http://localhost:8585/".

When I go to http://localhost:8585/ in my browser i have this -> It works!

When i try a curl  localhost:8585 in my computer (outside container) I have a lot of html looking like the Symfony homepage with : You're seeing this page because you haven't configured any homepage URL and debug mode is enabled. Welcome to
Symfony 5.4.24 blabla bla.

Do anyone have a solution to make it work?

Thank you,